# Creating 5 lists of the 5 same elements in different index order

Tags: python, list, permutation, randomized-algorithm

I'm struggling with a problem that seems so basic and yet drives me crazy as I'm still unable to implement.

Here's the deal:
I have a list with 5 elements, for instance :

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

I want the elements in the lists so that each list contains the same element at differents indexes. So for example, the element 'A' will have a different index position in each list. It should be randomize so that each time I run the code, I still have different lists.

like this:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
['C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B']
['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A']
['E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
['D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

I tried with itertools, I tried with if statement into for loops into for loops but obviously it didn't work... I feel like the solution is very simple but I'm missing something.

Comment: If you show the code you tried, someone may be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Do you _need_ them to be different, or can those five lists have duplicate orderings? @ScottHunter I don't think that would help in this case.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What's the rationale for that edit?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 always use a generic [python] tag for *all python related questions*. If a question is specific with respect to some python version, then you can add a version specific tag, although nowadays, since Python 2 is well passed it's EOL and no longer supported, Python is Python 3.

Comment: Your example doesn't look random, each row is just a rotation of the first. Is that intentional?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 yes, the 5 lists must contains the same elements but at different indexes. An element can't be the second of the list twice fir example..

Comment: But ['A','B','C','D'],['C','A','D','B'],['B','D','A','C'],['D','C','B','A'] would be a valid solution for ['A','C','B','D'], where the rows are not all rotations; correct?

Comment: Whatever algorithm you implement, you cannot guarantee that you'll get different results every time. That's the very nature of randomness

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `collections.deque` for this:

```py
from collections import deque

d = deque('ABCDE')

for _ in range(len(d)):
    print(d)
    d.rotate()

deque(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
deque(['E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
deque(['D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C'])
deque(['C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B'])
deque(['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A'])
```

To randomize, you'd shuffle the end result:

```py
import random

lists = []

for _ in range(len(d)):
    lists.append(list(d))
    d.rotate()

random.shuffle(lists)
```

Comment: That's the obvious one. However, it is not random.

Comment: @user2390182 no, but neither is OPs example. If the order should be random, then shuffle the order of rotations after the fact

Comment: Still won't be random if they are all rotations of each other.

Comment: @user2390182 *"So for example, the element 'A' will have a different index position in each list"*. Correct, because the desired effect isn't random

Comment: @user2390182 It's at least *somewhat* random. Unclear how much / what randomness the OP wants (so far they've ignored my question...).

Comment: @C.Nivs I love you ! That's exactly what I needed ! The random part is the order of the initial list (the argument for deque, in your example, it can be ('abcde') or ('aecdb') etc.). Anyway, thanks a lot for this !!!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is as random as your constrains permit, but it's at least a lot more random than your example while keeping all the constraints: Start with the "shifted" lists as in your example, then randomly shuffle the rows *and columns* of the matrix (or, maybe simpler, shuffle rows, then transpose, then shuffle rows again).

```
import random

lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
lsts = [lst[i:] + lst[:i] for i in range(5)]
random.shuffle(lsts)
lsts = list(map(list, zip(*lsts)))
random.shuffle(lsts)
```

Afterwards, each row and column contains each element exactly once, without any obvious pattern. Sample output:

```
['C', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'B']
['B', 'E', 'C', 'D', 'A']
['E', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'D']
['A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'E']
['D', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'C']
```

Comment: (I came up with this idea for generating "variations" of Sudoku boards that have a proper unique solution instead of implementing a full Sudoku-generating algorithm; the constraints --one of each number in each row and column-- are the same as in your case.)

Comment: For some reason, using `random.seed(0)` the result is rather un-random (I was using that at first for reproducible results), but with a random seed, the result indeed seems random.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit tricky. You can use `itertools.permutations` to create all possible permutations and then throw out those that don't match the constraint.

But since you get all permutations you get values like `['B', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'C']` and `['B', 'A', 'E', 'C', 'D']` in that order. Now the second permutation will always be thrown out. So you have to shuffle all permutations first.

```
import itertools
import random

def has_same_index(list_of_lists, list_to_compare):
    for inner_list in list_of_lists:
        for x, y in zip(inner_list, list_to_compare):
            if x == y:
                return True
    return False


data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

combis = list(itertools.permutations(data, 5))
random.shuffle(combis)

result = []
for combi in combis:
    if not has_same_index(result, combi):
        result.append(combi)
print(result)
```

This will give you results like

`[('A', 'C', 'E', 'B', 'D'), ('D', 'E', 'C', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'A'), ('E', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'C'), ('B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'E')]`

or

`[('D', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'A'), ('B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E'), ('E', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C'), ('C', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'D'), ('A', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B')]`.

If you need the tuples to be lists it's easy to convert them.

Comment: thanks for this solution, that is one of the solution I tried but never achieved... I'll keep it too !

Answer (score -1):

```
import random

original_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

# Number of lists you want to generate:
num_lists = 5

# Generate and print the shuffled lists:
for i in range(num_lists):
    shuffled_list = original_list.copy()
    random.shuffle(shuffled_list)
    print(shuffled_list)
```

You can change the code according to how many lists you want.

Comment: Since this is random you can't guarantee that you get the elements at different indexes. You might even get back the order of the original list.

Comment: @Matthias yep, you right, that's my concern here...